# como generar divs con css Skew e imagenes dentro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy queriendo armar una galería como el ejemplo de pagina que adjunto [pagina de guía](http://www.igxgamingexpo.com/) donde dice TOURNAMENTS que es un carousel y tiene imágenes en diagonales con hovers, arme un pequeño ejemplo pero no logro poder hacer que las imágenes queden rectas. Como podría hacer para generar el hover como en el ejemplo que adjunto?

```css
.grilla{
  height: 524px;
}
.grilla ul li{
    width: 21%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 304px;
    background-color: #f00;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 50px auto;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
    transform: skew(-25deg);
    margin: 68px 18px;

}
.grilla ul li a{

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="grilla">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="images/imagen-batman.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
              <div class=""></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="images/imagen-batman.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="images/imagen-batman.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="images/imagen-batman.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
            </li>            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas.

La idea es agregarle el atributo `transform: skewX(-30deg);` a los `li` para que se vean inclinados y a el `div` dentro de el ponerlo al contrario `transform: skewX(30deg)` así vuelve la imagen a la normalidad.

> NOTA: para cortar la imagen hay que ponerle a los `<li>` `overflow:hidden` y así completamos el efecto de inclinación sin deformar la imagen.

espero te ayude saludos.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```css
.grilla{
  height: 524px;
}
.grilla ul {
     opacity: 1;
    width: 1100px;
  
}
.grilla ul li{
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
    width: 20rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 27.75rem;
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.grilla ul li>div:hover {
transform: translate3d(0, -4.125rem, 0) skewX(30deg);
}

.grilla ul li>div {
transition:all .3s ease;
 width: 180%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40%;
    top: 0;
    transform: skewX(30deg)
}
.grilla ul li img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: center/cover no-repeat;
    display:block;
    border:0;
}
.grilla ul li:hover .btn {
opacity: 1;
transform: translate(0);/*Nuevo codigo para link en botones*/
z-index:100;/*Nuevo codigo para link en botones*/
}
.btn {
transition:all .3s ease;
    width: 13.3125rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4.5rem;
    left:6.2rem;
    box-shadow: -1.5625rem -0.6875rem 5.4375rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #5113b3;
    transform: translate(0,20px);/*Nuevo codigo para link en botones*/
}
/*Nuevo codigo para link en botones*/
.btn:hover {
  background: #5113b3;
}
.btn a {
  display:block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  
}
.btn:hover a{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="grilla">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li>
            
            <div>
              <img style="background-image: url('https://d2tt6uttc4o7qf.cloudfront.net/sites/596cf1c8afc5b3395c349466/content_entry596cf1f5afc5b33958807728/596cf219afc5b3395c3494d9/files/slant-call-of-duty.png?1500314315')" src="">
              <div class="btn"><a href="https://www.google.co.ve/">Results</a></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div>
              <img style="background-image: url('https://d2tt6uttc4o7qf.cloudfront.net/sites/596cf1c8afc5b3395c349466/content_entry596cf1f5afc5b33958807728/596cf21aafc5b3395c3494dc/files/slant-league-legends.png?1500312090')" src="">
              <div class="btn"><a href="https://www.google.co.ve/">Results</a></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div>
              <img style="background-image: url('https://d2tt6uttc4o7qf.cloudfront.net/sites/596cf1c8afc5b3395c349466/content_entry596cf1f5afc5b33958807728/596cf21aafc5b3395c3494df/files/slant-super-smash-bros.png?1500312091')" src="">
              <div class="btn"><a href="https://www.google.co.ve/">Results</a></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
           
              <div>
              <img style="background-image: url('https://d2tt6uttc4o7qf.cloudfront.net/sites/596cf1c8afc5b3395c349466/content_entry596cf1f5afc5b33958807728/596cf21cafc5b3395c3494e5/files/slant-gear-of-war.png?1500312092')" src="">
              <div class="btn"><a href="https://www.google.co.ve/">Results</a></div>
              </div>
            </li>            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Definición**

> La función CSS define una transformación que sesga un elemento en el plano 2D. Su resultado es un tipo de datos.skew()
>
> Esta transformación es un mapeo de corte ( transvección ) que distorsiona cada punto dentro de un elemento por un cierto ángulo en las direcciones horizontal y vertical. Las coordenadas de cada punto se modifican por un valor proporcional al ángulo especificado y la distancia al origen; por lo tanto, cuanto más lejos del origen se encuentre un punto, mayor será el valor agregado.

Comment: Claro es exactamente lo que quería Luis, y el efecto de hover de los textos y logo que aparecen como el ejemplo eso ya tendría q hacérselo con jquery?

Comment: no amigo todo lo puedes lograr con `css`, si la respuesta es correcta y soluciona tu problema dale como aceptada para que los demas programadores solucionen si tienen un problema igual

Comment: Perfecto Luis! probare hacerlo entonces. gracias

Comment: Ya le agregue el botón espero te ayude saludos

Comment: muchas gracias capo!

Comment: excelente poder ayudarte amigo

Comment: Hola Luis perdona que te moleste, estuve probando tu ejemplo y quería hacerte una consulta para ver si se puede hacer, cuando uno pasa por encima de las imágenes viste que le agregaste un botón en estado hover, hay alguna posibilidad de que ese botón este por fuera de la caja y darle con z index para llevarlo por encima de la imagen que el boton se posicione sobre el borde top de la imagen? se entiende?

Comment: Explícame mejor la funcionalidad y te la agrego con mucho gusto al ejemplo saludos

Comment: Hola Luis como estas? lo que quiero es que el boton de ficha quede por arriba para poder hacerle click y que me lleve a otro sitio. porque le agregue al a href un link pero no lleva al vinculo que le pongo

Comment: Listo amigo ya te agregue la funcionalidad espero sea lo que necesitas cambia el href de los `a` y listo ahorita manda a google , agregue un efecto mas agradable  y el `hover` del botón.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Luis.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que debes hacer es revertir el efecto `skew` en las imágenes con el valor contrario al que diste a su elemento padre.

```css
.grilla{
  height: 524px;
}

.grilla ul li{
    width: 21%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
    transform: skew(-25deg);
    margin: 68px 18px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.grilla ul li img{
  -webkit-transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.8);
  -moz-transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.8);
  -o-transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.8);
  -ms-transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.8);
  transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.8);
   transition: transform 0.3s;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.grilla ul li img:hover{
  -webkit-transform: skew(25deg) scale(2.2);
  -moz-transform: skew(25deg) scale(2.2);
  -o-transform: skew(25deg) scale(2.2);
  -ms-transform: skew(25deg) scale(2.2);
  transform: skew(25deg) scale(2.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="grilla">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="https://icueva.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/m78_2400x1600v.jpg">
              <div class=""></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="https://icueva.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/m78_2400x1600v.jpg">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="https://icueva.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/m78_2400x1600v.jpg">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="https://icueva.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/m78_2400x1600v.jpg">
            </li>            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Te digo como consejo que trates de nunca aplicar estilos `inline` como tenias el `width` y `height` de tus imágenes, siempre trata de usar la hoja de estilos.

Comment: si si solo que use esos estilos en linea para probar. esta bien lo que hiciste, pero como haría para que esten digamos dentro de cada div osea sin que tomen la forma del div del css y que no generen blancos ( que no se vea el color de fondo del div) se comprende?

Comment: mas que nada es para no tener que armar las imágenes en diagonal si uno quisiese reemplazarlas

Comment: @MarianoFranco he editado mi respuesta !

Comment: muchas gracias camilo

Comment: @MarianoFranco si la respuesta resolvió tus dudas te invito a que consideres marcarla como aceptada, así será de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, saludos!